# Browsing Nodes Won't Work

Tags: java, eclipse, opc, milo

Dear Stackoverflowers,

I'm  trying to browse the attributes of a node through OPC UA. OPC UA Milo (a free implementation of the standard) has an example server which I'm running on Eclipse and it works fine. My client is the UaExpert which connects with the server and where I try to browse the nodes from. But when I'm trying to browse the nodes I get a exception. I don't know why.

Does anyone know what the problem might be?

Details:

**Security Policy using** = none.

**User** = anonymous.

[UaExpert Exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/50wj0.png)

Thanks.

Comment: Are you running the *unmodified* example server or have you made some changes?

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply and excuse me for the late response. 

I only added some comments to the example server. I also downloaded the most recent version of Milo and compared it with the version I got. And it didn't show differences in the code.

Comment: Are you sure all files are compiling? I saw this once before when someone was running out of Eclipse. One of the Browse-related classes wasn't compiling due to an Eclipse bug recognizing some Java 8 syntax, but Eclipse still happily ran the example thanks to partial compilation and threw a weird exception when it hit that code path.

Comment: After cleaning and building the project I am pretty sure all the files are compiling. Eclipse doesn't show any errors only warnings. 

Thanks for your response, really appreciate it.

Comment: Not sure what else to look for. Anything in the logs? I'm running the `ExampleServer` class and UaExpert connects and browses with no issues. Double check that the `BrowseHelper` class is compiling - that's the one the other person had an issue with. If that doesn't work maybe try running from the command line.

Comment: Thanks Mr Herron I will check it out and keep you up to date.

Comment: Hi Mr Herron. I found out something juicy. In the very beginning of my study in Milo I encountered a fierce obstacle. The example, wouldn't run due to an error. http://imgur.com/a/MFpEB

After I told one of my colleagues about it, he "solved" it by commenting that part out and returning null. The one thing is I don't understand the exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It work's! After updating Eclipse I cleaned and build the project again. The sublime attributes display. Thanks for the help!

[image: Figure 1]
[image: Figure 2]